ValueError: time data "2020-04-29T17:18:25.574824Z" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", at position 3 - I am changing object dtype to datetime
I am trying change object dtype to datetime
# My Code:

import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'Channel_Started': ['2013-05-18T04:46:00Z', '2018-01-16T15:55:22Z', '2016-12-12T05:00:55Z', '2020-04-29T17:18:25.574824Z', '2023-11-24T21:56:18.571502Z', '2020-06-13T05:20:37.182391Z', '2015-08-22T13:22:51Z', '2016-11-16T14:52:31Z', '2020-05-09T20:35:27.233665Z', '2022-03-16T22:09:57.246468Z', '2023-02-11T05:55:01.369504Z', '2023-03-10T12:18:40.189285Z', '2005-12-16T09:01:28Z', '2013-09-05T01:15:06Z', '2017-07-13T09:30:23Z', '2020-08-05T16:09:28.304314Z']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert to datetime
df['Channel_Started'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Channel_Started'])

# Extract date
df['Channel_Started'] = df['Channel_Started'].dt.date

print(df)

Output:
# ValueError: time data "2020-04-29T17:18:25.574824Z" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", at position 3. You might want to try:

- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

Based on the error output provided, it seems that there is an issue with the format of the datetime string "2020-04-29T17:18:25.574824Z" not matching the expected format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z". The code is attempting to convert this string to a datetime object using the Pandas library in Python, but it is encountering a ValueError because the format specified does not match the actual datetime string.
I expecting This output:
   Channel_Started
0       2013-05-18
1       2018-01-16
2       2016-12-12
3       2020-04-29
4       2023-11-24
5       2020-06-13
6       2015-08-22
7       2016-11-16
8       2020-05-09
9       2022-03-16
10      2023-02-11
11      2023-03-10
12      2005-12-16
13      2013-09-05
14      2017-07-13
15      2020-08-05


H:%M:%S%z doesn't include milliseconds or microseconds. while :25.574824Z does. The error is correct

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have mixed formats. The actual format can be inferred for each value as follows:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Channel_Started": [
        "2013-05-18T04:46:00Z",
        "2018-01-16T15:55:22Z",
        "2016-12-12T05:00:55Z",
        "2020-04-29T17:18:25.574824Z",
        "2023-11-24T21:56:18.571502Z",
        "2020-06-13T05:20:37.182391Z",
        "2015-08-22T13:22:51Z",
        "2016-11-16T14:52:31Z",
        "2020-05-09T20:35:27.233665Z",
        "2022-03-16T22:09:57.246468Z",
        "2023-02-11T05:55:01.369504Z",
        "2023-03-10T12:18:40.189285Z",
        "2005-12-16T09:01:28Z",
        "2013-09-05T01:15:06Z",
        "2017-07-13T09:30:23Z",
        "2020-08-05T16:09:28.304314Z",
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Channel_Started"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Channel_Started"], format="mixed")

print(df)

Output:
                    Channel_Started
0         2013-05-18 04:46:00+00:00
1         2018-01-16 15:55:22+00:00
2         2016-12-12 05:00:55+00:00
3  2020-04-29 17:18:25.574824+00:00
4  2023-11-24 21:56:18.571502+00:00
5  2020-06-13 05:20:37.182391+00:00
6         2015-08-22 13:22:51+00:00
7         2016-11-16 14:52:31+00:00
8  2020-05-09 20:35:27.233665+00:00
9  2022-03-16 22:09:57.246468+00:00
10 2023-02-11 05:55:01.369504+00:00
11 2023-03-10 12:18:40.189285+00:00
12        2005-12-16 09:01:28+00:00
13        2013-09-05 01:15:06+00:00
14        2017-07-13 09:30:23+00:00
15 2020-08-05 16:09:28.304314+00:00

